# Skip download dialog box in IE using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I need to open a document on click on a button.

For that I use window.open() method. All work well when a document type is JPEG, DOC, TIFF etc.

When document type is MSG file (Outlook mail) or any document that cannot be open in IE, the browser asks to download a file with Open, Save, Cancel options.

I need to skip this dialog box and directly start download and open a document in its native application (that happens when user clicks on Open button in download box, so I need to do it via javascript or jQuery).

I tried to use IFrame and its Source attribute, that also gives the same result.

Any Suggestions..?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Browsers always ask this. Otherwise websites could send the visitors all kinds of things without them knowing.

Comment: You can use a data stream or a different URI protocol. See http://dtsn.me/2013/03/12/downloading-data-from-localstorage/ for an example of the datastream, it may not be possible for what you want. Otherwise you can see if the application has it's own protocol, like 'mailto' which opens an email client or 'spotify' which opens spority when a like like 'spotfy:link.to.a/playlist' is clicked.